# Add buttons interface to my console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I´m creating a project where I must synchronize a turntable and a depth sensor starting run.
What I want to do is starting all the process by inputting some predefined parameters through some buttons and then start the process.

My code is in Visual Studio 2010 c++, at the moment is a console application.

Am I using the appropriate solution? Is WPF the right thing for my project? or what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

if you have created your original application correctly, you should just be able to convert it to a class library, that once complied can be referenced in any other project. This would enable you to call your code from any other project type, e.g. ASP.NET WPF, etc...

Check out: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/61b832/creating-class-library-in-visual-C-Sharp/